# Media player for putting titles' names on taskbar

Tags: media-player

My music library is very large and there are many songs that I don't know/forget the name. I am seeking for a media player or an addon so that when new song is playing, its title and singer information will show permanent in the taskbar.

I use Win 8.1. My current player is VLC, it has a function that make a bubble notification when new song is played. This is the best that I can find, but not fully satisfy me because:

1. Keep appear and disappear, makes me distracted.
2. Disappear after a while.

My other prefers:

- Have tree in playlist (like in VLC)
- Can also display title in taskbar in Linux

Thank you.

Comment: VLC Player displays the title and artist in its taskbar button when you have grouping turned off in the taskbar properties

Comment: Even when I turn off the grouping icon, the displayed text isn't long enough to show all required information.